# Magento2 admin tab product grid filter reload issue

Tags: magento2, module, grid, ajax

I have been struggling with this for a couple days now... I have created a module that add a new tab to the customer admin page.

It works fine when loading and displaying the information I need but when I use the filters to find a product it reloads the whole tab instead of just the current grid overwriting the whole container.

In short I have 1 controller to generate the page from the following layout

> Morello\Customerproducts\view\adminhtml\layout\customerproducts_index_customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="content" label="Root">

        <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\Frame" name="customer_product_edit_frame"  template="Morello_Customproducts::frame.phtml">

            <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\CustomerProducts" template="Morello_Customproducts::products.phtml" name="customer_products">
                <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\CustomerProductsGrid" name="customer_products_grid" as="customer_products_grid" />
            </block>

            <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\Search" template="Morello_Customproducts::search.phtml" name="customer_product_search">
                <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\SearchProductGrid" name="customer_product_search_grid" as="customer_product_search_grid" />
            </block>

        </block>

    </container>

</layout>
```

As you can see I actually have 2 grids `customer_products_grid` and `customer_product_search_grid` for simplicity I will focus on the latter because I need to understand the process and I'll apply it to the former as well later on...

The grid module class file reference by `\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\SearchProductGrid` contains the following

> Morello\Customerproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\SearchProduct.php

```
<?php

namespace Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class SearchProductGrid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    private $productCollectionFactory;
    private $sessionQuote;

    public function __construct(
        //...
    )
    {
        //...
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        //..
    }

    public function getStore()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        //...
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        //...
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        //...
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /*************************************************************************/

    // I KNOW I HAVE TO USE THIS TO GET WHAT I WANT BUT I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW

    /*************************************************************************/
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'customproducts/*/???', ['_current' => true, 'collapse' => null]
        );
    }

}
```

This is currently my ONLY controller

> Morello\Customerproducts\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Customer.php

```
class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->initCurrentCustomer();
        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

WHAT AM I MISSING?

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as per usual, I figured it out right after posting my question... Argh... I'll post the solution since there is a frustrating lack of documentation about M2.

This part of my grid block file was modified as follows

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'customproducts/*/reloadgrid', ['_current' => true, 'collapse' => null]
    );
}
```

the `getUrl()` method is given the path to a new controller I use to reload the grid (through `customproducts/*/reloadgrid` parameter).

Here is the content of the new controller

> Morello/Customproducts/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/ReloadGrid.php

```
<?php

namespace Morello\Customproducts\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class ReloadGrid extends Action
{
// Let's get down to business, shall we?
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultInterface;
    protected $resultRaw;

    /**********************************************************************
    *
    * In the construct I collect the info I'll need in the execute() method
    * namely the PageFactory, ResultPageFactory and Raw result to provide
    * the interface the method must return
    *
    ***********************************************************************/

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, Raw $resultRaw)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultRaw = $resultRaw;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *
    * This is where it got tricky for me.
    * I'll walk through the steps one by one (because I wish someone would
    * have done it while I was searching for a solution...)
    *
    ***********************************************************************/

    public function execute()
    {   
        // First step is to create a ResultPageFactory
        // to retrieve the result for the filtered table
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        // In order to update the grid we can reload the original
        // block used to render it in the first place but if you
        // look at my question you'll see that my template file
        // 'customerproducts_index_customer.xml' has a nested
        // structure with the grid block/class already inside 
        // a couple of blocks, so rather than refactoring that
        // I created a new template just for reloading the grid
        // which I called 'customproducts_search_grid_handle.xml'
        // for simplicity. (content is attached below)

        // Second step is to provide the block to render to the 
        // ResultPageFactory we instantiated in step 1 by passing
        // our handle name
        $resultPage->addHandle('customproducts_search_grid_handle');

        // Once our ResultPageFactory knows what we want we can
        // Ask it to extract the layout and render the element 'content'
        $result = $resultPage->getLayout()->renderElement('content');

        // This was the trickiest step for me. Since the execute mthod
        // of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action must return either
        // a ResultInterface or a ResponseInterface I needed to find
        // a class that would allow me to get the content in the desired
        // format so I used Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
        // which extends AbstractResult which extends ResultInterface
        // and then we can call the setContents() method providing
        // the element we rendered in the 3rd step...
        return $this->resultRaw->setContents($result);

        // Easy-Peasy right?
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the new layout for the handle

> Morello/Customproducts/view/adminhtml/layout/customproducts_search_grid_handle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="\Morello\Customproducts\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Page\SearchProductGrid" name="customer_product_search_grid" as="customer_product_search_grid" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

As you can see it just contains the instance of the block we already used when creating the grid the first time.

I hope this helps somebody avoiding a few days of despair.